# How to fix performance of sortable editable list in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

My `List` renders many `ListItems` (using `react-list` to reduce the number on the page).

The `ListItems` have editable textareas that update the `listItems` part of my redux store on every keypress.

The `List` gets an array of `ListItem` ids in `mapStateToProps` based on some sorting criteria. It repeats this action a lot because `state.listItems` is getting updated on every keypress.

To try and combat the repetition I'm using [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), but considering `state.listItems` is one of the inputs to the selector it doesn't really cache since it's changing on every keypress. To combat THAT on every keypress I now map through all of the ListItems and grab their ids (and a few other things needed for sorting criteria) then pass that into a selector that does a [deepEquals check](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-why-is-my-selector-recomputing-when-the-input-state-stays-the-same) before sorting and caching.

That has improved performance but it's still a little laggy when typing with extremely large lists.

The problem is it's still mapping through all `ListItems` on every keypress.

The only solutions I can think of is to either keep an array of `ListItem` ids somewhere else in the store, and have to keep it up to date every time one gets added or deleted. But that seems annoying since it's really derived data. Or detach my textarea from the store, make it an uncontrolled input so it updates the store less frequently. Not ideal since there are some other things that are listening out for those changes that need to update as the user is typing.

I've seen a few other questions of a similar nature regarding using reselect for arrays of objects, but no answers seem to have a proper solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps one solution might be to [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) your input keypress event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there are some other components whose interactions depend on the text updates getting triggered in real time, but still a good idea